# Putting values of an array into text boxes using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I've created a dimensional array using two `for` loops, and as each inner loop completes, I'd like those values to go into textboxes on a windows form.  (I realize that the values will be overwritten each time, with just the values from the final outer loop showing at the end.)

The comments in the code show what I've been trying to get to work.

Thanks!

```cs
if (IsValidData())
{
    int Columns = 5;
    int Rows = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumbDrawings.Text);
    
    int[,] ball = new int[Columns, Rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
    {
        List<int> ballsList = new List<int>();
        int[] txtBall = new int[Columns];

        for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
        {
            Random number = new Random();
            ball[i, j] = number.Next(1, 70);
            
            // prevent duplicate numbers
            while (ballsList.Contains(ball[i, j] ))
            {
                ball[i, j] = number.Next(1, 70);
            }
            
            ballsList.Add(ball[i, j]);

            /*************************************************
             * how do I get the current ball value
             * into a textbox on a form?
             * 
             * textboxes are named txtBall1, txtBall2, etc...
             * 
             * I was trying something like:
             * 
             * TextBox[] txtBall = new TextBox[5];
             * for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
             * {
             *      txtBall[i + 1].Text = ball[i, j].ToString();
             * }
             *************************************************/
        }

        ballsList = null;
    }
}

Windows Form Image:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak6hxvO3Ye6Oj5I9NQy834Yk4TRLyw?e=DniwK8
```

Comment: What do you expect from this code?

Comment: Put each `lstBall1` into an array and index that array.

Comment: How many drawings are there?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, and that seems to be assigning a shuffled list of integers to one of 5 list boxes, then this should do it:

```
if (IsValidData())
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    
    // (1, 69) because rnd.Next(1, 70) only produces the numbers 1 to 69
    int[] shuffled_balls = Enumerable.Range(1, 69).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

    ListBox[] list_boxes = new [] { lstBall1, lstBall2, lstBall3, lstBall4, lstBall5 };

    for (int i = 0; i < shuffled_balls.Length; i++)
    {
        list_boxes[i % list_boxes.Length].Items.Add(shuffled_balls[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I misspoke, I'm trying to add the ints into textboxes, not listboxes.  This is just a learning / practice thing, Powerball.  So I'm drawing 5 pseudo-random white balls, then 1 red powerball.  The number of drawings is based upon txtbox where the user enters a number.  I'll edit my original post with corrected/additional info.  Thanks!